# React getting error 400 when trying to login using firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

When I try to run the code is as follows.
I don't know exactly where the error is and I'm new please be understanding. thank you for your help.

```
function Login (props) {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    let errorsObj = { email: '', password: '' };
    const [errors, setErrors] = useState(errorsObj);
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    function onLogin(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      let error = false;
      const errorObj = { ...errorsObj };
      if (email === '') {
          errorObj.email = 'Email is Required';
          error = true;
      }
      if (password === '') {
          errorObj.password = 'Password is Required';
          error = true;
      }
      setErrors(errorObj);
      if (error) {
          return;
      }
      dispatch(loadingToggleAction(true));
      signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
          // Handle successful login
          dispatch(loginAction(email, password, props.history));
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
  }
```

[image: error image]